# Django - De-dupe a List and Keep the Dupes

Tags: python, django

I'd like to de-dupe the below list, but also keep a list of the duplicates to display on the following screen. This is pulled from a CSV file, so it'd be great to display the user what's been added and what hasn't been added "Dupes" etc.

```
[
  ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'],
  ['Danny', 'Lastnme', 'name@email.com'],
  ['Sally', 'Surname', 'name@email.com'],
  ['Sally', 'Surname', 'name@email.com'],  < -- Dupe
  ['Sally', 'Surname', 'name@email.com'],  < -- Dupe
  ['Chris', 'Lastnam', 'name@email.com'],
  ['Larry', 'Seconds', 'name@email.com'],
  ['Barry', 'Barrins', 'name@email.com'],
  ['Glenn', 'Melting', 'name@email.com'],
  ['Glenn', 'Melting', 'name@email.com'],  < -- Dupe
]
```

The ultimate result would be to generate two lists, one of the nice de-duped results and the other a list of the duplicates.

Unique:

```
[
  ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'],
  ['Danny', 'Lastnme', 'name@email.com'],
  ['Sally', 'Surname', 'name@email.com'],
  ['Chris', 'Lastnam', 'name@email.com'],
  ['Larry', 'Seconds', 'name@email.com'],
  ['Barry', 'Barrins', 'name@email.com'],
  ['Glenn', 'Melting', 'name@email.com'],
]
```

Dupes:

```
[
  ['Sally', 'Surname', 'name@email.com'],
  ['Sally', 'Surname', 'name@email.com'],
  ['Glenn', 'Melting', 'name@email.com'],
]
```

Comment: Do you need to keep the information how many dupes there are, or is it enough to say "Sally Surname was found multiple times"?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Just updated the question. What would be perfect is a way to get back a unique list and a dupe list, ala:  `{ 'unique': [], 'dupes': [] }` Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy and paste this code to get a return dictionary of dupes and uniques:

```
a = [
['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'],
['Danny', 'Lastnme', 'name@email.com'],
['Sally', 'Surname', 'name@email.com'],
['Sally', 'Surname', 'name@email.com'],  
['Sally', 'Surname', 'name@email.com'], 
['Chris', 'Lastnam', 'name@email.com'],
['Larry', 'Seconds', 'name@email.com'],
['Barry', 'Barrins', 'name@email.com'],
['Glenn', 'Melting', 'name@email.com'],
['Glenn', 'Melting', 'name@email.com'],
]

result = {}

b = [tuple(x) for x in a[1:]]
all_uniques = set(b)
result['unique'] = [list(x) for x in list(all_uniques)]

# To show which ones have duplicates use Mr Es solution:

from collections import Counter

t = Counter(b)
dupes = []

for k, v in t.iteritems():
    if v > 1:
        dupes.append(list(k)*(v-1))

result['dupes'] = dupes

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. This is easiest way.

```
name_list = [
    ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'],
    ['Danny', 'Lastnme', 'name@email.com'],
    ['Sally', 'Surname', 'name@email.com'],
    ['Sally', 'Surname', 'name@email.com'],  
    ['Sally', 'Surname', 'name@email.com'], 
    ['Chris', 'Lastnam', 'name@email.com'],
    ['Larry', 'Seconds', 'name@email.com'],
    ['Barry', 'Barrins', 'name@email.com'],
    ['Glenn', 'Melting', 'name@email.com'],
    ['Glenn', 'Melting', 'name@email.com'],
]
sorted_name_list = sorted(name_list[1:])
last_record  = False
Unique = []
Dupes = []
for record in sorted_name_list:
    if last_record != record:
        Unique.append(record)
    else:
        Dupes.append(record)
        last_record = record
print Unique
print Dupes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the frequency with

```
from collections import Counter

t = Counter(tuple(x) for x in data[1:])

uniques = [list(k) for k, v in t.iteritems() if v == 1]
dupes = [list(k) * (v-1) for k, v in t.iteritems() if v > 1]
```

Comment: These are great, thanks mr-e and @tim-pietzcker. Only one question regarding the duplicates, how can I (excuse me if it's in plain site) make it list all duplicates, even if the duplicates are duplicates themselves. At the moment the above data set is only showing two Dupes, where there are three. Know what I mean?

Comment: Thanks Mr E, this will also do the trick. Really appreciate it.

Comment: One thing Mr E, the `uniques` take out all the duplicates, not keeping any of them in place. That said, I wasn't too obvious about that. Apologies.